# How does mat-autocomplete classList Input work?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

According to the [MatAutocomplete documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete), there is a `classList` input to style the panel.

> @Input('class') classList: string | string[]
>
> Takes classes set on the host mat-autocomplete element and applies
> them to the panel inside the overlay container to allow for easy
> styling.

When I do `<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" classList="test-class">` I expected that I would see the test-class added to the mat-autocomplete-panel? But this does not work.

Can someone please explain how this input is to be used?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-classlist?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out. The docs say that it takes classes **"set on the host mat-autocomplete"**.

That's the part I missed. You need to set `class="test-class"` as well

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" class = "test-class" classlist="test-class">
```

I also realized that the css must be in your app's base `styles.css file` and not in your component css file for it to work. It's probably because your panel will be inside an overlay outside of your component

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-classlist-answer?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.css)

### Edit

OR as Ankit Singh pointed out in his answer, you can use `::ng-deep` if you still want to do it in the component css file...

```
::ng-deep .test-class {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Clutch for putting it in the global .css file. For some reason, some of my classes will apply when in mat-option or mat-autocomplete, but some will only apply when they are in the global styles file. Not sure why. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: I don't get why styling `mat-select` panels and `mat-autocomplete` panels don't just work the same...

Comment: The `bindingPropertyName` of `classList`  input is `class`. No need to use `classList` on `mat-autocomplete`.

Answer (score 1):

As per Pieter Buys Anwser i would to add

you can ng-deep

in .css file if you want you css to be encapsulated

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-classlist-answer-h9jcw8)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize (without classlist and still with encapsulation), in your **style.css**

```
.mat-autocomplete-panel:hover {
  .mat-option:hover {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
  }
}
```